# How to check if a NSMutableArray contains a value (null) or not?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have an `NSMutableArray` instance which contains "N" number of objects and I want to check whether `NSMutableArray` contains a (null) or any other value.

In `NSString` there is a method called `isEqualToString:` Is there a similar method available for `NSMutableArray`?

Or otherwise, how can I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`NSMutableArray` can only contain non-`nil` objects. Objects that print as `(null)` are typically `nil`.

The superclass method `containsObject:` will tell you whether a particular non-`nil` object is in the array. Note that this will only work if the objects are identical according to `isEqual:`.

Comment: Hi walkytalky,
Thanx for reply but if i have a (null) i.e a value of emptystring then how can i check?

Comment: An empty string will not print as `(null)`. If it does, it's `nil` and you don't have to look for it in the array because it can't be there. (Okay, it could also be `@"(null)"` -- you can test for this with `containsObject:` as added above -- but that's pretty unlikely. Unless you're wilfully defining that string just to confuse yourself?)

Comment: yes walkytalky you are correct when i print my mutablearray with CFShow(mutablearray); it shows exactly what you said.It is simply nil.
Thanks for help.